# Sum Multiple values in different Rows using Vlookup Function

Tags: excel, vlookup

```
A        B   
France  152 
Italy   255 
France  221 
Spain   215 
USA     222 
Spain   155
```

I desire to add each value occurring in front of repeating countries using Vlookup function

Solution:

```
A       B
France  373
Spain   370
```

Comment: In this case you need `SUMIF`, not `VLOOKUP`. For example `=SUMIF(A:A,"France",B:B)` would sum all values in the B column where "France" is in the A column.

Answer (score 3):

If you use a SUMIF then you can total the columns

If the data starts in cell A1 then in cell C2 type

```
=SUMIF(A:A,A3,B:B)
```

then drag the formula down. this will give totals for each country

Or if you just want to show the first instance (where it says France for example) then use

```
=IF(COUNTIF(A$1:A2,A2)=1,SUMIF(A:A,A2,B:B),"")
```

You won't be able to do it with a vlookup.

You could use a pivot table which might be easier and that is useful for this exact type of question.

Answer (score 3):

To get the list of repeating countries enter the following formula in `Cell D2`

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$2:$A$7,MATCH(1,INDEX((COUNTIF($D$1:D1,$A$2:$A$7)=0)*(COUNTIF($A$2:$A$7,$A$2:$A$7)>1),0,0),0)),"")
```

Then to get sum of corresponding country, in `Cell E2` enter

```
=SUMIF($A$2:$A$7,D2,$B$2:$B$7)
```

Drag/Copy formulas as required. See image for reference.

[image]